# position of string in hive array

Tags: arrays, indexing, position, hive

Say I have an array in Hive:
arr = ['A','B','C','D']

Is there a way to get the position/index of an element from this array?

Something like index(arr,'C') which will give me 2/3?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

simple function to get position of item

```
function getPosition(array,item){
return array.indexOf(item)+'/'+ (array.length-1);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var arr=['A','B','C','D'];    
alert(getPosition(arr,'C'));
//return 2/3
```